# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} \int_{x}^{2x} e^{-t^{2}}\,dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

> How to evaluate this limit ?
>   $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} \int_{x}^{2x} e^{-t^{2}}\,dt$$

Can we use L'hospital rule here?

Comment: Hint: Expand the integrand for small $t$ and convince yourself that only the first term contributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using $\frac{d}{dx}(\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} h(t)dt)=h(f(x)).f'(x)-h(g(x)).g'(x)$ And the L hospital rule we have $L=\lim{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-4x^2}.2-e^{-x^2}.1}{1}=1$

Answer (score 3):

$e^{-t^2}$ is a "bell curve"

$\frac{1}{x}\int_x^{2x} e^{-t^2} \ dt$

asks what is the average height of the grey stripe

[image]

The limit as $x$ approaches $0$ moves the grey stripe over to the $y$ axis.

$\lim_\limits{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}\int_x^{2x} e^{-t^2} \ dt = \lim_\limits{t\to 0} e^{-t^2}$

Comment: It is better to use theorems like FTC to justify the intuition presented here.

Comment: We are really using the MVT here even if I did not call it out.

Answer (score 3):

$F(x)=\displaystyle {\int_{x}^{2x}}e^{-t^2}dt$;

MVT, FTC:

$\dfrac{F(x)-F(0)}{x}=F'(s)$, $0<s<x$, where

$F'(s)= 2e^{-(2s)^2}-e^{-s^2}$;

Note: $\lim x \rightarrow 0 $ implies $ \lim s \rightarrow 0$.

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{F(x)-F(0)}{x}=$

$\lim_{s \rightarrow 0}(2e^{-(2s)^2}-e^{-(s)^2})=1$;

OR, a bit shorter:

MVT for integrals:

$I(x):= \displaystyle{ \int_{x}^{2x}}e^{-t^2}dt =$

$ e^{-s^2}\displaystyle {\int_{x}^{2x}}1dx = xe^{-s^2}$, $s \in [x,2x].$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{I(x)}{x}= \lim_{s \rightarrow 0}e^{-s^2}=1$;

Answer (score 0):

If we let:
$$f(x)=e^{-x^2},\,F(x)=\int f(x)dx$$
Then we can say that:
$$L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{F(2x)-F(x)}{x}$$
and since we can see that:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}F(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}F(2x)$$
we know that our limit is of the form $\frac 00$ and so we can say:
$$L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{F'(2x)-F'(x)}{1}=\lim_{x\to 0}\left[2f(2x)-f(x)\right]=\lim_{x\to 0}\left[2e^{-4x^2}-e^{-x^2}\right]=2-1=1$$

Answer (score 0):

The substitution $t=ux$ also works:

$$\lim_{x\to0}{1\over x}\int_x^{2x}e^{t^2}\,dt=\lim_{x\to0}\int_1^2e^{x^2u^2}\,du=\int_1^2\left(\lim_{x\to0}e^{x^2u^2} \right)\,du=\int_1^21\,du=1$$

The step in which the limit is brought inside the integral can be justified from the fact that

$$\left|\int_1^2(e^{x^2u^2}-1)\,du \right|\le\left|\int_1^2(e^{4x^2}-1)\,du \right|=e^{4x^2}-1$$

Answer (score 0):

L'Hospital's Rule is unnecessary here.

By Fundamental Theorem of Calculus we have $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}\,dt=e^{-0^2}=1$$ and hence $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}\int_{x}^{2x}e^{-t^2}\,dt=\lim_{x\to 0}2\cdot\frac{1}{2x}\int_{0}^{2x}e^{-t^2}\,dt-\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}\,dt=2\cdot 1-1=1$$